# Using Search and Replace in Eclipse, how do you replace a string with a multi-line String

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

[image: Eclipse find and replace]

Using the eclipse Search and replace functionality, I was to search for a single line string and replace it with a multi-line string.  I already attempt to use \n and /n to insert a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You just have to ensure the "Regular Expression" box is checked before performing the search.  Then in the replace dialog you will also have a "Regular Expression" box which must be checked.  Then you separate each new line with a new line character "\n" in the replacement string.

Example:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->\n     <script type="text/javascript">\n code\n
```

Comment: You should be able to copy the multi-line to-string from the editor and paste it into the find/replace dialog box.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  I'm using STS 2.9.2.RELEASE.  I was able to get it to work by using new line characters: "\n"